# Non-Static member variables creation like static singleton creation in C++

Tags: c++, templates, static, non-static, class-members

First, I really like the pattern of lazy initialization of singletons. I use it in the following way to get different kind of data with varying value types (The example is simplified):

```
class A
{
    template<typename T>
    const T& getData() const
    {
        static T data;
        return data;
    }
}
```

I know that the `data` variable is not connected to any instances of the class and that it exists until the program ends.

But what I want now, is that each instance of the class A should hold the variables in a non-static way and still there should be the flexibility of calling `.getData<bool>()` or with any other data type, without the need to specify each possible data type in the class definition.

Is that possible? I have not come up with an idea to implement that.

I thought of something with a container like:

```
template<A*, typename T>
class DataContainer
{
    T data;
}
```

With that one can extend the code to:

```
class A
{
    template<typename T>
    const T& getData() const
    {
        static DataContainer<this, T> container;
        return container.data;
    }
}
```

But that does not compile.

Does anybody of you have an idea how to implement that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one idea, using Boost.any:

```
#include <typeinfo>
#include <type_index>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <boost/any.hpp>

struct ThingGetter
{
    template <typename T>
    T & get()
    {
        auto key = std::type_index(typeid(T));
        auto it = things.find(key);

        if (it == things.end())
        {
            it = things.emplace(key, boost::any(T())).first;
        }

        return boost::any_cast<T&>(*it);
    }

    std::unordered_map<std::type_index, boost::any> things;
};
```

This simple version assumes that each type can be value-initialized and creates a value-initialized value if no entry for the requested type exists. Alternative implementations could return a pointer that might be null and have a separate insertion interface.

Usage:

```
ThingGetter mythings;

mythings.get<bool>() = true;
mythings.get<double>() = 1.5;
return mythings.get<int>();
```